# How to get data from CKeditor to database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ckeditor

How to get data from `textarea` CKEditor to database?

My view:

```
 <form action="#" id="form">
      <div class="input group">
        <label>Deskripsi :</label>
        <textarea class="ckeditor" name="desc" id="desc"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Simpan</button>
    </form>
```

My JavaScript:

```
function save()
{
  var url;
  if(save_method == 'add')
  {   
      url = "<?php echo site_url('admin/kategori/proses_tambah_kat  ')?>";
  }
  else
  {
    url = "<?php echo site_url('index.php/book/book_update')?>";
  }

   // ajax adding data to database
      $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {
           //if success close modal and reload ajax table
           $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
          location.reload();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error adding / update data');
        }
    });
 }
```

if without using CKEditor, data has been entered to database.

Comment: is your CKeditor is initializing if so first check form browser NETWORK wich data are posted to that network. AND then check the field type of that field from PHPMYADMIN

Answer (score 0):

The `data` you should be posting to the server is `CKEDITOR.instances.desc.getData()`.

See also the official documentation [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_savedata).